# Trying to Understand How to connect 74LS173A in Digital Works

Tags: integrated-circuit, ground, datasheet, wiring, vcc

A little bit of background first: I found an older application that seems to be very versatile. It is called Digital Works. You can find it [here](https://www.mecanique.co.uk/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=89).

Within this application you are able to use basic logic gates, flip flops, clocks, inputs and outputs etc, to build a circuit. Once you have the logical circuit built you can use it's template function to set pin associations from the logical part to a macro.

For example, you can use a set of gates to build a 4 bit register which is what I'm currently working on within this application. Then once you use the template tool to build the casing of the I.C. and associate the pins, you can then create this as a macro. After you are done with this you will be able to use this chip within other circuits. This is a nice level of abstraction so that you wouldn't have to build this again every time you needed a 4 bit register.

I built the logical part and tested it with interactive inputs and outputs and everything worked as expected. Then I removed the interactive inputs and replaced them with the application's tag device which is used to associate pins within the logic part to the integrated circuit.

I'm implementing a SN74LS173A Chip. I have all of the logic working. I'm now working on the outer chip (macro) part and assigning the pins. I'm trying to keep the same pin ordering as the real chip. Here is a link to the PDF of the data sheet of the chip I am building. [sn74ls173a.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls173a.pdf)

- Page 1 Shows me the pin layout which is what I'm trying to mimic when associating the pins in the macro.
- Page 3 Shows the Logic Diagram in which I have completed; there are no issues here as far as the logic is concerned.
- Page 4 Shows the schematics of the inputs and outputs and that they are internally connected to Vcc and Ground.

What I'm missing here; is if I go back to the logical diagram, I don't know how to run the wiring for the Vcc and Ground to create connection points for them to the interface part of the chip (macro). The data sheet doesn't show this directly and I'm a bit confused here...

Comment: Is this a long winded question on how to wire Vcc and ground to a chip?

Comment: @Andyaka No not to a chip, but within the chip... this is where I'm confused. The interface of the chip has pins for Vcc and Ground for external connections. It is the internal design of the chip that has the logic gates. I don't know if any of the wiring within the logic part is connected to the Vcc and or Ground or not... This is where I'm confused.

Comment: Logical diagrams usually omitting these connections as they are not related to the *logic*. Can you show your diagram?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Within the program that I'm using; I have the logic diagram setup with its built in gates just as the PDF data sheet shows. I tested them with interactive I/O.  Now I replaced those interactive I/O's with the programs "Tag Device" which enables you to associate that to a pin when creating the interface part of the chip. I'm trying to keep the same pin ordering which isn't an issue. It is the Vcc and Ground pins of the interface part... there is nothing within the logical part to associate them with...

Comment: the power pins are irrelevant in the logic simulator ... they have nothing to do with logic diagrams, therefore not simulated

Comment: @jsotola okay thank you, I wasn't completely sure or not, but if I'm building this chip for the simulator; should I still incorporate the pins to the interface part of the chip?

Comment: you do whatever you feel that you must do ... there is nothing left to add to the subject

Comment: @josotola It's okay I just wanted clarity... For example on the macro or IC chip I do have the Vcc and Ground pins, but as you stated they are not connected to the actual logical interface. So I just associated the I/O's of the logical interface to the macro's pin ordering.